# Confusion on accelerations of system of cart, blocks, and pulley

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Problem: Initially, the system of objects shown in Figure P5.93 is held motionless. The pulley and all surfaces and wheels are frictionless. Let the force F be zero and assume that $m_1$ can move only vertically. At the instant after the system of objects is released, find (a) the tension T in the string, (b) the acceleration of $m_2$, (c) the acceleration of M, and (d) the acceleration of $m_1$. (Note: The pulley accelerates along with the cart.)

[image: Fig. P5.93][image]

My professor provided the following second law equations for $m_2$, $M$, and $m_1$, respectively.
$$\tag{1} m_2 (a-A) = T$$
$$\tag{2} MA = T$$
$$\tag{3} m_1 a = m_1 g - T$$

However, when he solved for the acceleration of $m_2$, he used $a$ as its acceleration and when he solved for the acceleration of $m_1$, he used $a-A$. But isn't it the other way around according to the second law equations or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: I think your prof just got mixed up with m1 and m2

Comment: Is that 2nd diagram yours?

Comment: @ChetMiller no it's from the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are confused with the accelerations so taken of each body , then it is simply that
Your professor has simply approached the question with the block of mass  'M ' at rest i.e. w.r.t. to the block of mass "M" being the observer and to do so , given is to be the acceleration of mass 'M" along x-axis to each body in opposite direction as mass "M" s motion (if that body is free to move along x-axis only ).